# Is there a portable way to represent an arbitrary database table (structure is only known at run-time) similar to the way a DataSet/DataTable does?

Tags: c#, .net, database, data-structures, portable-class-library

I have a wrapper library for an API that queries user defined databases. It is currently working well using DataSet, DataTable, DataRow, etc. I would like to convert it to a portable library for use on other platforms but these classes are not part of the portable subset.

**Is there anything that is even remotely equivalent to these classes?** The main thing that my library does with the DataSet is to transfer data into a domain layer, which populates the business objects.

What I need is a way to pass an arbitrary representation of a database table from my library to the program calling my library that works on some form of the portable library, ideally all subsets (Xbox not required) but anything is better that the nothing I have now.

**Background**

This is the data flow that I'm struggling with

```
User Defined Database <==> My Library <==> User C# Code
```

The API that is available is rough around the edges. My library makes querying it much easier, but since I don't know anything about the structure at design time, I parse the returned data from the API and put it into DataSet objects. The end user's parses those DataSets to populate their domain objects. What I'm looking for is a way to do this for a portable library, without a DataSet.

Example of the usage of my library, this is also the extent of features of DataSet/Table/Row that are used:

```
var myLib = new MyLib(parms);
Find request = myLib.MakeFind();
request.AddSearch("userID", 12);
DataSet response = request.Execute()

var user = new User();
user.ID = int.Parse(response.Tables[0].Rows[0]["userID"].ToString());
user.FirstName = response.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FIRST_NAME"].ToString();
user.LastName = response.Tables[0].Rows[0]["LAST_NAME"].ToString();

foreach (DataRow relatedRow in dr.GetChildRows("Logs"))
{
    var lg = new LogEntry() { ID = int.ParserelatedRow["ID"].ToString()), Text = relatedRow["Text"].ToString(); };
    user.Logs.Add(lg);
}
```

Comment: `DataSet` is a pretty powerful model. Are you looking for as close as possible drop in replacement? Or are you looking for anything? The number of ways of storing data is pretty large.

Comment: @Guvante I just updated my post to include the most complex usage of the returned DataSet.

Comment: Can you describe exactly what would be missing with simple serialization (XML/JSON/etc.)? From what I'm reading, it sounds like you just need to transform data into something portable, and then into objects - simple serialization handles that. Maybe you can start there and add on whatever's missing.

Comment: @JoeEnos So my output would then just be a giant string of json? My issue with that is then users of my library need to parse my serialized string, which may or may not be better than the API I'm trying to wrap up. If it helps, the current version of the library is [here on GitHub](https://github.com/WizardSoftware/fmDotNet)

Comment: I'd expect any decent programming environment to handle XML serialization natively, or at least with an existing free library. JSON may not be 100%, but I'd bet most languages can do it. If you have a list of the platforms you're sending your data to, a quick web search should tell you if it supports XML and/or JSON.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest basic serialization (XML/JSON) - it makes the data portable, and it's available to use in pretty much any platform you can think of. XML may be slightly more common than JSON, but you could always take the approach that WebAPI does - let the caller decide which of the two they want, defaulting to XML if they don't pick one.

Serializing/deserializing data into XML or JSON is trivial in .NET, assuming you're not doing anything too crazy. Deserializing in other platforms should be straightforward, but you can probably dig up examples for any programming environment with a quick web search.